# Java Multi Threading Code gets stuck in a normal run mode in IDE but debug mode makes it work

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I am new to Java Multi-Threading and was trying to create a program where there are 2 threads. One which prints out Odd Numbers and one which Prints out even numbers. Now, I want all numbers from 1 to 1000 printed in order such that each thread takes a turn. I have created a Turn object which is shared by the 2 objects and hence can be used for signalling 1 thread from the other! The code is given below

```
public class Turn {
        public static int whoseTurn = 1;

        public static int getWhoseTurn() {
            return whoseTurn;
        }
}

public class Main {

    public static class EvenThread extends  Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 2;
            while(i < 1000){
                if(Turn.getWhoseTurn() == 2) {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + " is an even number ");
                    i = i  + 2;
                    Turn.whoseTurn = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class OddThread extends  Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 1;
            while( i <  1000){
                if(Turn.getWhoseTurn() == 1) {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + " is an odd number ");
                    i = i + 2;
                    Turn.whoseTurn = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread evenThread = new EvenThread();
        Thread oddThread  = new OddThread();

        oddThread.start();
        evenThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        evenThread.join();
        oddThread.join();


    }

}
```

I have 2 issues with this code.

1. The code when run in a normal run mode gets stuck anywhere from count 380 - 690. But, when run in a debug manner initially without breakpoints again gets stuck there but then if a breakpoint is added after it gets stuck, I understand where the code is and a run button again runs the code. Why does my code get stuck in a normal run mode and how do I avoid that?
2. Is there a race condition possible for this solution or is this solution a perfect solution for coordination between the threads? I can't think of any case where this code would fail to produce results?

Comment: What does "code gets stuck" mean exactly?

Comment: It starts printing numbers like 1 is an odd number, 2 is an even number and so on and it will print till 380 is an even number and just stops printing further . Doesn’t print anything further on the terminal but the program has not died also...

Answer (score 0):

```
The code when run in a normal run mode gets stuck anywhere from count 380 - 690. But, when run in a debug manner initially without breakpoints again gets stuck there but then if a breakpoint is added after it gets stuck, I understand where the code is and a run button again runs the code. Why does my code get stuck in a normal run mode and how do i avoid that?
```

^^ this happens because of busy wait. *Even* thread could be waiting (looping for its turn) never conceding/giving chance to *Odd* thread to run. And since *Odd* thread did not run, *Even* thread would not make any progress - giving the program a **stuck** state where no progress is being made. You could add a sleep at the end of loops in both threads to solve this (alternatively use wait/notify to avoid time wastage due to sleep). In debug mode, you essentially make a thread to pause (giving chance to other thread to proceed)

```
Is there a race condition possible for this solution or is this solution a perfect solution for coordination between the threads? I can't think of any case where this code would fail to produce results?
```

^^ multi threading programs are hard to debug and test. Currently I don't see any issues as well but would recommend comparing it with already available solutions to understand what is being differently with your logic and why.

Answer (score 0):

Rishabh's answer theoretically highlights what could be going wrong. In short, just before things go wrong, one thread (can be either even or odd thread) is printing the odd/even number and then changing the whoseTurn variable so that the next thread can print the other number. However, the problem is with the latter i.e. even though the value is changed in memory, the second thread is somehow unable to read the latest value.
This is because the controlling variable whoseTurn is not a volatile variable. In java, every thread has local copy of variables in the cache. That means every read of the variable is done from the cache which may or may not be equal to the variable's value in the main memory. For Java, “volatile” tells the compiler that the value of a variable must never be cached.
For more information regarding volatile you can refer to  [oracle documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

To verify the above, you can add the below line to your program and execute the same.

```
public  volatile static int whoseTurn = 1;
```

Comment: You are correct that volatile is needed because currently there is a data race. But caches are always coherent. So if you write a value to the cache, it is guaranteed that any other cache will see this value as well. In this case the important part is that volatile prevents certain compiler optimizations that prevent the thread from seeing the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the input regarding compiler optimization. But I don't think all caches are coherent though most modern caches are.

Comment: I don't know any modern mainstream CPU that doesn't have coherent caches. Even the older ones like PowerPC, Itanium.